# Show custom fields based on user input in Xamarin Forms with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project with MvvmCross. In one screen, I have a combo box to choose a field type: `string`, `number`, `list` or `date`. When a type is chosen, I have to show a custom input for the selected type: if it's `string`, I have to show a normal `Entry`, if it's `Date`, a `DatePicker`, etc.

How I can do that?

Comment: It's easy with Flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add in your ViewModel property `FieldType`.
2. Bind it to all types of inputs like this:
   `IsVisible="{Binding FieldType, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualConverter}, ConverterParameter=current_field_type}"`
3. Create `IsEqualConverter` and inside compare `FieldType` with parameter.

It will show and hide input fields based on selected `FieldType`. You can read more about converters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters